# I am trying to create a simple timer in Typescript, in the browser console it says "this.pad is not a function" and I don't get why

Tags: angular, typescript

I am well aware this is not very Angular friendly, in fact I'd like to know from you a better fix to make it more "Angular-y" if possible, thank you.

```js
export class TimerComponent implements OnInit {
  min = 0;
  sec = 0;
  minutesLabel: any = document.getElementById('minutes'); 
  secondsLabel: any = document.getElementById('seconds');

  startTimer() {
    const interval = setInterval(this.setTime, 1000); 
    return interval;
  }

  setTime() {
    ++this.sec;
    var r: any = this.sec / 60;
    this.secondsLabel.innerHTML = this.pad(this.sec % 60);
    this.minutesLabel.innerHTML = this.pad(parseInt(r));
  }

  pad(val: any) {
    var valString = val + '';
    if (valString.length < 2) {
      return '0' + valString;
    } else {
      return valString;
    }
  }

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 3):

You have a few solutions here:

```
setInterval(this. setTime.bind(this), 1000);
```

or:

```
setInterval(() => this.setTime(), 1000);
```

The reason being that when you pass `setTime` into `setTimeout`, the `this` scope of your object instance isn't preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a answer that also makes it as you said "Angular-y".

This makes use of rxjs timer which is similar to setTimeout but more configurable, form prod use you will need some way to unsubscribe on destroy.

I also simplified a lot here that was not needed, as well as added better type definitions.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  minutesLabel: string;
  secondsLabel: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    timer(0, 1000).subscribe((sec) => {
      this.secondsLabel = this._pad(sec % 60);
      this.minutesLabel = this._pad(Math.floor(sec / 60));
    });
  }

  private _pad(val: number) {
    var valString = val + '';
    if (valString.length < 2) {
      return `0${valString}`;
    } else {
      return valString;
    }
  }
}
```